# How to create a Draggable JLabel that snaps into certain bounds on a panel

Tags: java, swing, draggable, jlabel, venn-diagram

I'm working on a Venn Diagram GUI application in Java which requires me to create elements (JLabels) that can be dragged and then dropped in the circular Venn Diagram sections. Presently I have two (custom made) circular J Panels that are overlapping.

Two Questions Arise: 
1) How can I create J Labels which can move around the screen and ultimately snap into certain bounded spots of the Label and fit within bounds. 
 2) How am going to create a layout on the J Panels themselves that will only allow the text elements to fit in the certain spots and not overlap.

Here's what my GUI looks like so far. I've marked it up to show you a general idea of the interface and how I would like the functionality to work

[image]

Comment: This type of application is not what Swing components were designed for.  I'd just create a drawing JPanel and draw everything on the Venn diagram.  Keep the Swing components on a control JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go... About 463 lines of code to get you started...

```
public class Final {

    public static enum MouseEventFlag {
        KEY_ALT, KEY_ALTGRAPH, KEY_CTRL, KEY_META, KEY_SHIFT, BUTTON_LEFT, BUTTON_MIDDLE, BUTTON_RIGHT;

        public static EnumSet<MouseEventFlag> buttonSetOf(final MouseEvent mevt) {
            final EnumSet<MouseEventFlag> set = EnumSet.noneOf(MouseEventFlag.class);
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(mevt)) set.add(BUTTON_LEFT);
            if (SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(mevt)) set.add(BUTTON_MIDDLE);
            if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(mevt)) set.add(BUTTON_RIGHT);
            return set;
        }
    }

    //Converts EnumSet to mask:
    public static long pack(final EnumSet<?> set) { //Supports Enums with up to 64 values.
        //return set.stream().mapToLong(e -> (1L << e.ordinal())).reduce(0L, (L1, L2) -> L1 | L2);
        long L = 0;
        for (final Enum e: set)
            L = L | (1L << e.ordinal());
        return L;
    }

    //Converts Enums to mask:
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> long pack(final E... ez) { //Supports Enums with up to 64 values.
        long L = 0;
        for (final Enum e: ez)
            L = L | (1L << e.ordinal());
        return L;
    }

    public static Color transparent(final Color c, final int alpha) {
        return new Color(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), alpha);
    }

    public static void setOperatedSize(final Dimension input, final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> operator, final Dimension inputOutput) {
        inputOutput.setSize(operator.apply(input.width, inputOutput.width), operator.apply(input.height, inputOutput.height));
    }

    //Prompts user to input some text.
    public static void inputTitle(final Component parent, final String titleID, final Consumer<String> consumer) {
        final String userIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "Enter " + titleID.toLowerCase() + "'s title:", "Enter title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (userIn != null) {
            if (userIn.isEmpty())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, titleID + "'s name cannot be empty...", "Oups!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            else
                consumer.accept(userIn);
        }
    }

    //Applies an action to every child component of the container recursively as well as to the given Container.
    public static void consumeComponentsRecursively(final Container container, final Consumer<Component> consumer) {
        for (final Component child: container.getComponents())
            if (child instanceof Container)
                consumeComponentsRecursively((Container) child, consumer);
            else
                consumer.accept(child);
        consumer.accept(container);
    }

    public static Dimension getGoodEnoughSize(final Component comp, final Dimension defaultSize) {
        final Dimension dim = new Dimension(defaultSize);
        if (comp != null) { // && comp.isVisible()) {
            /*Start with default size, and then listen to max and min
            (if both max and min are set, we prefer the min one):*/
            if (comp.isMaximumSizeSet())
                setOperatedSize(comp.getMaximumSize(), Math::min, dim);
            if (comp.isMinimumSizeSet())
                setOperatedSize(comp.getMinimumSize(), Math::max, dim);
        }
        return dim;
    }

    public static class ManualLayout implements LayoutManager, Serializable {

        public Dimension getLayoutComponentSize(final Component comp) {
            return getGoodEnoughSize(comp, (comp.getWidth() <= 0 && comp.getHeight() <= 0)? comp.getPreferredSize(): comp.getSize());
        }

        @Override public void addLayoutComponent(final String name, final Component comp) { }
        @Override public void removeLayoutComponent(final Component comp) { }
        @Override public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(final Container parent) { return minimumLayoutSize(parent); } //Preferred and minimum coincide for simplicity.

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(final Container parent) {
            final Component[] comps = parent.getComponents();
            if (comps == null || comps.length <= 0)
                return new Dimension();
            final Rectangle totalBounds = new Rectangle(comps[0].getLocation(), getLayoutComponentSize(comps[0]));
            for (int i = 1; i < comps.length; ++i)
                totalBounds.add(new Rectangle(comps[i].getLocation(), getLayoutComponentSize(comps[i])));
            return new Dimension(totalBounds.x + totalBounds.width, totalBounds.y + totalBounds.height);
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(final Container parent) {
            for (final Component comp: parent.getComponents())
                comp.setSize(getLayoutComponentSize(comp)); //Just set the size. The locations are taken care by the class's client supposedly.
        }
    }

    public static abstract class RectangularPanel<R extends RectangularShape> extends JPanel {
        private R shape;
        private Area cache; /*Use a cache so as not to have to create new Areas every time we need
        to intersect the clip (see 'createClip' method). Also, the client can modify the current
        shape but not the cache upon which the shape and painting of the panel depend.*/

        public RectangularPanel(final double width, final double height) {
            super();
            super.setOpaque(false);
            cache = new Area(shape = createShape(0, 0, width, height));
            super.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent cevt) {
                    cache = new Area(shape = createShape(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        protected abstract R createShape(final double x, final double y, final double width, final double height);
        protected abstract double getArcWidth();
        protected abstract double getArcHeight();
        protected final R getShape() { return shape; }
        @Override public boolean contains(final int x, final int y) { return cache.contains(x, y); }

        protected Shape createClip(final Shape originalClip) {
            if (originalClip == null)
                return cache;
            final Area clip = new Area(originalClip);
            clip.intersect(cache);
            return clip;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(final Graphics g) { //print() and update() rely on paint(), so we only need to override this one...
            g.setClip(createClip(g.getClip()));
            super.paint(g);
        }
    }

    public static class VennTool implements Runnable {

        protected static final Object LAYER_USER_CONTROLS = JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER, LAYER_VENN_SET = JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER, LAYER_VENN_LABEL = JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER;

        public class VennDrawPanel extends JPanel {

            private final JLayeredPane pane;
            private final int drawingOffsetY, drawingOffsetX;
            private final JCheckBox attachMode, collisionMode;
            private final JPanel ctrl;

            public VennDrawPanel(final GraphicsConfiguration gconf) {
                super(new BorderLayout());
                pane = new JLayeredPane();
                super.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                final ManualLayout layout = new ManualLayout();
                pane.setLayout(layout);
                final Dimension prefsz = new Dimension(gconf.getBounds().getSize());
                prefsz.width = (2 * prefsz.width) / 3;
                prefsz.height = (2 * prefsz.height) / 3;
                final JButton createLabel = new JButton("Create label");
                final JButton createSet = new JButton("Create set");
                attachMode = new JCheckBox("Attach mode", true);
                collisionMode = new JCheckBox("Collision mode", true);
                ctrl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 5));
                ctrl.add(createLabel);
                ctrl.add(createSet);
                ctrl.add(attachMode);
                ctrl.add(collisionMode);
                drawingOffsetX = layout.getLayoutComponentSize(ctrl).width;
                prefsz.width = Math.max(prefsz.width, drawingOffsetX);
                drawingOffsetY = prefsz.height / 8;
                pane.setPreferredSize(prefsz);
                pane.add(ctrl, LAYER_USER_CONTROLS);
                createLabel.addActionListener(e -> inputTitle(this, "Label", VennTool.this::createLabel));
                createSet.addActionListener(e -> inputTitle(this, "Set", VennTool.this::createSet));
            }

            protected void setControlsEnabled(final boolean enable) { consumeComponentsRecursively(ctrl, c -> c.setEnabled(enable)); }
            public boolean isAttachModeSelected() { return attachMode.isSelected(); }
            public boolean isCollisionModeSelected() { return collisionMode.isSelected(); }
            protected Point getCreationLocation() { return new Point(drawingOffsetX + 50, drawingOffsetY / 2); }

            public void addSet(final VennSet set) {
                set.setLocation(getCreationLocation());
                pane.add(set, LAYER_VENN_SET, 0);
                pane.revalidate();
                pane.repaint();
            }

            public void addLabel(final VennLabel label) {
                label.setLocation(getCreationLocation());
                pane.add(label, LAYER_VENN_LABEL, 0);
                pane.revalidate();
                pane.repaint();
            }
        }

        protected static class VennBorder extends LineBorder {
            public VennBorder(final int thickness) { super(Color.BLACK, thickness, true); }

            @Override
            public void paintBorder(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
                if (c instanceof VennControl) {
                    final VennControl ctrl = (VennControl) c;
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                    try {
                        g2d.setColor(ctrl.getBorderColor());
                        final int t2 = thickness + thickness;
                        final int aw = (int) Math.round(Math.min(width, ctrl.getArcWidth())), ah = (int) Math.round(Math.min(height, ctrl.getArcHeight()));
                        final Path2D path = new Path2D.Float(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD);
                        path.append(new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height, aw, ah), false);
                        path.append(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x + thickness, y + thickness, width - t2, height - t2, aw, ah), false);
                        g2d.fill(path);
                    }
                    finally {
                        g2d.dispose();
                    }
                }
                else
                    super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
            }
        }

        public static <C1 extends VennControl<C1, C2, ?, ?>, C2 extends VennControl<C2, C1, ?, ?>> void attach(final C1 c1, final C2 c2) { //Utility method.
            c1.getAttachments().add(c2);
            c2.getAttachments().add(c1);
        }

        public static <C1 extends VennControl<C1, C2, ?, ?>, C2 extends VennControl<C2, C1, ?, ?>> void detach(final C1 c1, final C2 c2) { //Utility method.
            c1.getAttachments().remove(c2);
            c2.getAttachments().remove(c1);
        }

        protected abstract class VennControl<C1 extends VennControl<C1, C2, R1, R2>, C2 extends VennControl<C2, C1, R2, R1>, R1 extends RectangularShape, R2 extends RectangularShape> extends RectangularPanel<R1> {
            private Color bg;
            private boolean highlighted, selected;
            private final LinkedHashSet<C2> attachments;

            public VennControl(final String title, final double width, final double height) {
                super(width, height);
                super.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                super.add(new JLabel(Objects.toString(title), JLabel.CENTER));
                super.setBorder(new VennBorder(2));
                super.setSize((int) Math.ceil(width), (int) Math.ceil(height));
                attachments = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                bg = transparent(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 127);
                highlighted = selected = false;
                final MouseAdapter relocationMA = new MouseAdapter() {
                    private Point moveAnchor;
                    private LinkedHashSet<C2> intersections;

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                        if (pack(MouseEventFlag.buttonSetOf(mevt)) == pack(MouseEventFlag.BUTTON_LEFT) && moveAnchor == null && intersections == null) {
                            VennTool.this.drawPanel.setControlsEnabled(false);
                            moveAnchor = mevt.getPoint();
                            setSelected(true);
                            intersections = findIntersections(0, 0);
                            intersections.forEach(c2 -> c2.setHighlighted(true));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                        final int dx = mevt.getX() - moveAnchor.x, dy = mevt.getY() - moveAnchor.y;
                        final boolean attach = VennTool.this.drawPanel.isAttachModeSelected(), collisions = VennTool.this.drawPanel.isCollisionModeSelected();
                        final LinkedHashSet<C2> newIntersections = findIntersections(dx, dy);
                        if (MouseEventFlag.buttonSetOf(mevt).contains(MouseEventFlag.BUTTON_LEFT) && moveAnchor != null && intersections != null && (!attach || newIntersections.containsAll(getAttachments())) && (!collisions || !collides(dx, dy))) {
                            setLocation(getX() + dx, getY() + dy);
                            LinkedHashSet<C2> setHighlight = (LinkedHashSet<C2>) intersections.clone();
                            setHighlight.removeAll(newIntersections);
                            if (!attach)
                                setHighlight.forEach(c2 -> detach(c2, (C1) VennControl.this));
                            setHighlight.forEach(c2 -> c2.setHighlighted(false));
                            setHighlight = (LinkedHashSet<C2>) newIntersections.clone();
                            setHighlight.removeAll(intersections);
                            setHighlight.forEach(c2 -> c2.setHighlighted(true));
                            intersections = newIntersections;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                        if (pack(MouseEventFlag.buttonSetOf(mevt)) == pack(MouseEventFlag.BUTTON_LEFT) && moveAnchor != null && intersections != null) {
                            intersections.forEach(c2 -> c2.setHighlighted(false));
                            final VennDrawPanel vdp = VennTool.this.drawPanel;
                            if (vdp.isAttachModeSelected())
                                intersections.forEach(c2 -> attach(c2, (C1) VennControl.this));
                            moveAnchor = null;
                            intersections = null;
                            setSelected(false);
                            vdp.setControlsEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                };
                super.addMouseListener(relocationMA);
                super.addMouseMotionListener(relocationMA);
            }

            protected LinkedHashSet<C2> findIntersections(final double dx, final double dy) {
                final R1 r1tmp = getShape();
                final R1 r1 = createShape(getX() + dx + r1tmp.getX(), getY() + dy + r1tmp.getY(), r1tmp.getWidth(), r1tmp.getHeight());
                final LinkedHashSet<C2> intersections = new LinkedHashSet<>(), possibilities = getPossibleIntersections();
                possibilities.forEach(c2 -> {
                    final R2 r2tmp = c2.getShape();
                    final R2 r2 = c2.createShape(c2.getX() + r2tmp.getX(), c2.getY() + r2tmp.getY(), r2tmp.getWidth(), r2tmp.getHeight());
                    if (intersect(r1, r2))
                        intersections.add(c2);
                });
                return intersections;
            }

            public LinkedHashSet<C2> getAttachments() { return attachments; }
            protected abstract boolean intersect(final R1 r1, final R2 r2);
            protected abstract LinkedHashSet<C2> getPossibleIntersections();
            protected abstract boolean collides(final double dx, final double dy);

            public void setHighlighted(final boolean highlighted) {
                if (highlighted != this.highlighted) {
                    this.highlighted = highlighted;
                    repaint();
                }
            }

            public void setSelected(final boolean selected) {
                if (selected != this.selected) {
                    this.selected = selected;
                    repaint();
                }
            }

            public void setColor(final Color c) {
                if (!bg.equals(c)) {
                    bg = Objects.requireNonNull(c);
                    repaint();
                }
            }

            public Color getBorderColor() {
                return selected? Color.GREEN: (highlighted? Color.CYAN: Color.BLACK);
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(bg);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        }

        protected class VennLabel extends VennControl<VennLabel, VennSet, Rectangle2D, Ellipse2D> {
            public VennLabel(final String title) { super(title, 0, 0); }
            @Override protected Rectangle2D createShape(double x, double y, double width, double height) { return new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height); }
            @Override protected double getArcWidth() { return 0; }
            @Override protected double getArcHeight() { return 0; }
            @Override protected boolean intersect(final Rectangle2D r1, final Ellipse2D r2) { return r2.intersects(r1); }
            @Override protected LinkedHashSet<VennSet> getPossibleIntersections() { return VennTool.this.sets; }

            @Override
            protected boolean collides(final double dx, final double dy) {
                Rectangle2D tmp = getShape();
                final Rectangle2D thisShape = createShape(getX() + dx + tmp.getX(), getY() + dy + tmp.getY(), tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight());
                for (final VennLabel label: VennTool.this.labels)
                    if (label != this) {
                        tmp = label.getShape();
                        tmp = label.createShape(label.getX() + tmp.getX(), label.getY() + tmp.getY(), tmp.getWidth(), tmp.getHeight());
                        if (tmp.intersects(thisShape))
                            return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected class VennSet extends VennControl<VennSet, VennLabel, Ellipse2D, Rectangle2D> {

            public VennSet(final String title, final double radius) {
                super(title, radius + radius, radius + radius);
                final Dimension sz = super.getPreferredSize();
                sz.width = sz.height = Math.max(Math.max(sz.width, super.getWidth()), Math.max(sz.height, super.getHeight()));
                super.setSize(sz);
            }

            @Override protected Ellipse2D createShape(double x, double y, double width, double height) { return new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height); }
            @Override protected double getArcWidth() { return getWidth(); }
            @Override protected double getArcHeight() { return getHeight(); }
            @Override protected boolean intersect(final Ellipse2D r1, final Rectangle2D r2) { return r1.intersects(r2); }
            @Override protected LinkedHashSet<VennLabel> getPossibleIntersections() { return VennTool.this.labels; }
            @Override protected boolean collides(final double dx, final double dy) { return false; } //Never collides with anything.
        }

        private final JFrame frame;
        private final VennDrawPanel drawPanel;
        private final LinkedHashSet<VennSet> sets;
        private final LinkedHashSet<VennLabel> labels;

        public VennTool(final GraphicsConfiguration gconf) {
            drawPanel = new VennDrawPanel(gconf);
            frame = new JFrame("Collisionless Venn Tool", gconf);
            sets = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            labels = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        }

        public void createSet(final String title) {
            final VennSet set = new VennSet(title, 100);
            sets.add(set);
            drawPanel.addSet(set);
            drawPanel.revalidate();
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }

        public void createLabel(final String title) {
            final VennLabel label = new VennLabel(title);
            labels.add(label);
            drawPanel.addLabel(label);
            drawPanel.revalidate();
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            else
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final VennTool tool = new VennTool(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            tool.createSet("Drag this set!");
            tool.createLabel("Drag this label!");
        });
        tool.run();
    }
}
```

### Why so many lines?

Mainly because you said what you have implemented but did not provide any code. So I had to design everything from scratch.
From a custom layout manager, to custom shaped panels and borders, to the actual *VennTool*, *VennDrawPanel*, *VennSet* and *VennLabel* representations.

### So what does it include?

Here is something like a class diagram which is my best effort so far for your requirements:

[image: Class diagram]

Boxes represent classes, pointers represent inheritance and nested boxes represent nested classes. Black text represents class names and cyan text represents comments/details.

The code starts with seemingly unrelated classes, but they act something like a framework to work with in the VennTool.

To start, `MouseEventFlag` enum is just there to convert `MouseEvent`s to enum constants so as to test which button/key is pressed for each mouse event.

Then there are some static methods that do general things like packing `EnumSet`s to `long` masks, converting colors to transparent, obtaining and operating on `Component` sizes etc...

Then there is the custom `LayoutManager` class, named `ManualLayout`. As the name suggests, you have to put the `Component`s of a `Container` with a `ManualLayout` to where you want them to be with (for example) `setBounds` or `setLocation` methods. Then the layout calculates a preferred size for each `Component` in the `Container` in order to return minimum and preferred layout sizes. The `layoutContainer` method simply sets the sizes of the included `Component`s and does not move their location. The `ManualLayout` takes into account all sizes of each `Component` (ie current size, preferred, minimum and maximum size). Instance of such a layout is used to lay out the `Component`s in the drawing panel (will talk about that in this post).

Then there is the `RectangularPanel` class which is a custom shaped `JPanel` which supports any `java.awt.geom.RectangularShape` shape to shape out the panel itself and paint it. This is a superclass of the components which compose a Venn set (such as the Venn set itself and the labels added to the drawing panel).

Then there starts the `VennTool` class. This class implements `Runnable` to run the *simulation*. It encloses all the classes representing Venn components/elements as well as the drawing panel. Client classes are only supposed to see the `VennTool` class (which provides methods for creating Venn sets and labels) and nothing else (except if they are subclasses of it). Handling and modifying the Venn sets is up to the user. You can of course modify the class to return all the Venn components already in the simulation at any time you need to save them as a project for example later, but such a functionality is not implemented here. Just add some getters and file I/O to do this yourself.

Then, inside the `VennTool` now, is the `VennDrawPanel` which is the drawing panel which I was talking about all above, which is responsible for the layout of the whole simulation. Here we add the Venn sets, labels and user controls (such as buttons to let the users define their actions). The `VennDrawPanel` has a `JLayeredPane` which uses a `ManualLayout`, achieving different layers and locations for each component. In particular, the first layer is composed by the buttons. On top of that layer are the Venn sets and finally on top of that are the Venn labels. As a future idea, you can implement a new layer on which the dragged component will go upon dragging (for example you may want a Venn set which the user is currently dragging to be at the layer which is above all others).

Then, there is the custom `Border` class, named (you guessed it) `VennBorder`. It is enclosed in `VennTool` only to show the scope of it and to allow it interact with each Venn component. It's purely inpired by and also extending `javax.swing.border.LineBorder` class.

Then, there is the `VennControl` class which represents each Venn component (ie `VennSet`s and `VennLabel`s). It is responsible to consume mouse guestures (such as dragging a Venn set around), for collision detection and resolution of labels and also responsible for attaching/detaching sets to labels and labels to sets.

The custom `VennBorder` and `VennControl` classes are defined by a shape of type `java.awt.geom.RectangularShape`. This allows that each subclass can be for example of `Ellipse2D` shape (as in the case of `VennSet`s which are circular) or a `Rectangle2D` (as in the case of `VennLabel`s). It also defines an arc width and height to support `RoundRectangle2D` but that just came along the road to support both `Ellipse2D` and `Rectangle2D` in a single panel/border.

Finally, there is the `VennSet` and `VennLabel` classes which represent a Venn set and a label to be added to a Venn set correspondingly.

### Attach/Detach mode:

While enabled, each mouse release will attach the label you hold with all overlapping sets (or the set you hold with all overlapping labels). It will also not let labels/sets go non-overlapping with their attached sets/labels. Disable this mode in order to move any `VennControl` freely around detaching it on mouse release.

### Collision detection mode:

As the name suggests, when enabled, labels will collide and not overlap with each other. While when disabled, they will not.

Comment: Imports of the Java code, do not fit in the answer.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc is this a problem? Is it big? I don't know. Shall I make it without generics at all? Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: Raw types can lead to class cast exceptions.  In your code, they're probably not as much of a problem.  They would be more of a problem if someone had to maintain or modify your code on a regular basis.  I just reacted when I put your code into my Eclipse, and the editor lit up with many yellow warnings.